# how to test for that alternating series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(n)}{n+1}$

i did the ratio test for this series and it shows that it is inconclusive because it is equal to 1 and the same thing for root test i guess

How to test for the convergence of this series then ?

Answer (score 1):

The terms do not have limit $0$: automatic divergence.

It is a theorem that **if** $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges, **then** $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Thus  if it is not true that the $a_n$ have limit $0$,  then the series $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ cannot converge.